# Razor Rendering issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

For some reason this is not rendering correctly.

I think I copied this method from another application, and seem to be missing something for razor to render correctly

MODEL has

```
   private void InitLogsToRetrieveOptions()
    {
        // TODO change this to retreive by DATE/TIME

        string logsToRetrieveConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[LogConstants.LogsToRetrieveConfig];
        var logsToRetrieveOptions = new List<string>(logsToRetrieveConfig.Split(','));
        var logsToRetrieveOptionList = new List<DropdownItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < logsToRetrieveOptions.Count; i++)
        {
            logsToRetrieveOptionList.Add(new DropdownItem("Top " + logsToRetrieveOptions[i], logsToRetrieveOptions[i]));

        }

        LogsToRetrieveOptions = new SelectList(logsToRetrieveOptionList, LogConstants.DropdownItemValue);


    }
```

WebConfig has

```
<...>
<add key="LogsToRetrieve" value="10,20,30,50" />
</appSettings>
```

and Index is

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLogsToRetrieve, new { id = "LogsToRetrieveLabel" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLogsToRetrieve, Model.LogsToRetrieveOptions)
```

To me this seems solid except for the fact my page looks like this
[image]

SO my question is why does this not work and i am making this applicaiton less M$oft Razor and more AngularJs ( should I handle this better in Angular.Js) and not work on fixing this. Yet I would also Like to know why this is not working ( general programmer compulsion need to know why .)

Edit : the model seems to build correctly I've set breakpoints.

Comment: Did you check to see what the values are in `model.SelectedLogsToRetrieve`? That's what's being displayed. I have a feeling you don't fully understand how Razor works. try `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LogsToRetrieveOptions)`, that way it's actually displaying `LogsToRetrieveOptions`

Answer (score 0):

I see it now the model was incorrect it should be

```
LogsToRetrieveOptions = new SelectList(logsToRetriveeOptionList, LogConstants.DropdownItemValue, LogConstants.DropdownItemDisplayName);
```

Hence the displayName was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `DropdownItem` class looks like, but you should be able to do this with the use of `SelectListItem` class which is for rendering the dropdown items.

```
string logsToRetrieveConfig = "10,20,30,50";
var logsToRetrieveOptions = new List<string>(logsToRetrieveConfig.Split(','));
var options = logsToRetrieveOptions
                  .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x, Text = x }).ToList();
LogsToRetrieveOptions = new SelectList(options);
```